# Multidimensional associative array - get key and value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

newbie ICT- student here with first post!
First of all big ups to to Stack Overflow community.
I'm spending more time finding answers here than sitting on class room, with more positive outcome, thank you!

To my problem:

I need to store key and value to separate PHP variables from multidimensional associative array.

Array looks like this with `var_dumb($data)`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Celestial Field"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cosmic Space Worm"]=>
    string(3) "234"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Dance For The Dawn"]=>
    string(3) "345"
  }
}
```

I'm able to get Key value with following:

$artName = key($data[1]); 
Returns "Celestial Field"

How to get that `string(3`) value from array and store it to `$artAmount`?
I tried:

```
$artAmount = array_values($data[1]);
```

But it only returns "Array".

Comment: $artAmount = $data[1]["Celestial Field"]; ?

Comment: Ok. that was easy. And if I need to get some other artAmount I can just use $artName as index. Thank you.

Comment: array_values returns an array, which prints Array when you echo it. You could use `array_values($data[1])[0]`, but I think you should use the comment above mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tests out OK

```html
<?php // demo/kasper.php
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479691/multidimensional-associative-array-get-key-and-value
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// TEST DATA
$data = array
( []
, [ "Celestial Field"    => "123" ]
, [ "Cosmic Space Worm"  => "234" ]
, [ "Dance For The Dawn" => "345" ]
)
;

$point = 1;
$artName = key($data[$point]);
$artAmount = $data[$point][$artName];
var_dump($artName, $artAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$artName = key($data[1]); //Returns "Celestial Field";

$artAmount = $data[$artName]; //Returns "123";
//--OR--
$artAmount = $data[key($data[1])]; //Returns "123";
```